# Having a fixed container which is aligned via flexbox. Is that possible

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-float, fixed

So I have 2 containers in another container, aligned side by side via flexbox. Only the content of one of these containers should be fixed to the top of the page.

Mark-Up:

```
<div class="outer-container">
  <div class="inner-container1">
    Blabla, some normal content in here!
  </div>
  <div class="inner-container2">
    <div class="fixed-box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.fixed-box {
  position: fixed;
}
```

But this doesn't work like I want to have it. Here the fixed-box is fixed but is displayed beside the outer-container.

What is wrong?
Thank you for your help!
Johanna

Comment: if you want it fixed why do you need the parent to be flex?

Comment: What you mean by fixed ???? you want it at the top of the container ? remain on scroll of page or reamin on scroll of container ?

Comment: Here is a JSFiddle for that: https://jsfiddle.net/8oro9e42/

Comment: I am using the flex to align the two containers side by side.
And the content of one of these containers should be fixed to the top of the page (so also when scrolling the page).

Comment: OK, I got it. Need to use flex-grow and flex-shrink! Works now.